# Encoding Image Same for Java and iOS

Tags: java, ios, encoding

I want to encode an image (gif file) in Java and pass it to iOS for displaying it.

Given below is my code in iOS

```
UIImage *w=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"label" ofType:@"gif"]];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(w);


NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64Encoding];
NSLog(@"encoding String :::%@",encodedString );

UIImage *imaged = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:encodedString]];

UIImageView *imag2=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

imag2.image=imaged;
[self.view  addSubview:imag2];
```

I am currently unable to get the same encoded result (`encodedString`) in Java.

Can any one suggest me some source code for generating same encoded data?

Comment: You talk about encryption but your code only mentions Base64, which is just a way to represent data and not encryption at all!

Comment: i want to know how to get the same string so that i can produce an image in ios also can any one tell me how to pass an image from Java to ios

Comment: You should be able to just generate the GIF in Java and display it without any encoding at all, unless you're pull it out of a plain text stream. Why do you want to base64 encode it? If you do need it, you have to use a third-party library, like Apache Commons or iharder: http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/

Comment: Actually the result of conversion of the image to byte array is different in java and IOS, also i was not using a proper tech                                     Anyways my issues is solved.........